# How to move all validating events to custom class?

Tags: vb.net, class, validation

i am new to programming so this might be a bit strange question.

I have a simple Form with couple of TextBoxes. I need to Validate user input, so i created Validating events for this TextBoxes.

```
Private Sub txtTest_Validating(sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtTest.Validating
    ValidateInputMinMax(CType(sender, Control), e)
End Sub
```

From this event handler i call private sub *ValidateInputMinMax*, where i use

```
ErrorProvider.SetError
```

and

```
e.canle = True
```

based on some validation criteria. I have couple of this handlers and private subs, that i would like to move from *Form Class* to new custom Class.
Can this be done?

I tried copying all this to custom class and declaring withevents:

```
Dim WithEvents txtTest as TextBox
```

Now i am stuck. Am i even on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Like this ..

```
Private Sub txtTest_Validating(sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtTest.Validating
    ValidateInputMinMax((CType(sender), Textbox),e)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand this. I forget to tell that this Validating event is not triggered when i move it from Form1 Class.

Comment: this handler only work in form1 class .. except you add the controls that handled .. such as **sub test_valid( .. ) handles txtBox2.Validating, form2.txtBox1.Validating**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegate.

```
Public Class Form1

  Friend WithEvents exampleControl1 As New ExampleControl


  Private Sub exampleControl1_Events(ByVal eventNumber As Integer) Handles_
 exampleControl1.Event1


  End Sub


End Class

Public Class ExampleControl
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

  Public Event Event1(ByVal eventNumber As Integer)

  Private Sub ExampleMethod()

    RaiseEvent Event1(1)

  End Sub

End Class
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/9e594807-49fd-448a-9804-6f5edd6cb2b0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx

Comment: Yvette thank you very much. I will try to get this working. I will report on my progress. Bon Appetit.